# Как воспроизвести "Грязное чтение"?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, транзакции, dba

Пытаюсь повторить ситуацию с "Грязным чтением".
БД Postgres. Две транзакции с уровнем ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED.
Первая Т1 обновляет значение в таблице.
Вторая Т2 читает это значение.
После этого Т1 падает с ошибкой и откатывается (rollback).

В результате обновленного значения от Т1 нет в БД ни в один момент времени. Это логично, ведь commit'а не было. Тогда как же воспроизвести "Грязное чтение"? Как заставить обновится значение в таблице до commit'а транзакции? Это возможно?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Судя по [вот этому вопросу и ответам](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165438/dirty-reads-in-postgres) на английском СО, внутри `Postgres` просто нет такого уровня изоляции. Там ссылаются на [документацию](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html):

> In PostgreSQL, you can request any of the four standard transaction isolation levels, but internally only three distinct isolation levels are implemented, i.e., **PostgreSQL's Read Uncommitted mode behaves like Read Committed**. This is because it is the only sensible way to map the standard isolation levels to PostgreSQL's multiversion concurrency control architecture.

То есть выбрать то вы уровень изоляции `Read Uncommitted` можете, но работать он будет всё-равно как `Read Committed`.

Так что никакого "грязного чтения" воспроизвести не получится, увы.

Comment: А очень хочется. Тогда нужно перейти на другую БД. Знайте в какой БД получится воспроизвести "Грязное чтение"?

Comment: @KonstantinEmelyanov Честно говоря не знаю. Попробуйте MS SQL или MySQL )

Answer (score 3):

Цитируя книгу "PostgreSQL 15 изнутри":

> За счет использования снимков данных изоляция в PostgreSQL отличается
> от той, что требует стандарт, и в целом она строже. **Грязное чтение не
> допускается по определению**. Формально в PostgreSQL можно указать
> уровень Read Uncommitted, но работать он будет точно так же, как Read
> Committed, поэтому дальше я вообще не буду говорить про этот уровень.
> Уровень Repeatable Read не допускает не только неповторяющегося, но и
> фантомного чтения (хотя и не обеспечивает полную изоляцию). Правда, на
> уровне Read Committed можно в ряде случаев потерять изменения.